# Python Package found missing in Image used for Deployment

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, pip, odoo

We are using odoo application and to deploy all required packages for the project, we customized the odoo docker image and installed additional packages on top of that.
I passed requirements.txt(including below packages) in Dockerfile but when launched pod with the image it shows below python packages missing:-
ebaysdk
pypiwin32
odoo-client-lib
unicodecsv
python-json-logger

So I added above python packages installation at the end of the Dockerfile after setting user Odoo:-

```
FROM odoo:14
USER root
RUN apt-get install -y libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev
WORKDIR /etc/odoo
COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 install pip --upgrade
RUN pip3 install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt
CMD chmod 755 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/*.py
USER odoo
RUN pip3 install odoo-client-lib
RUN pip3 install ebaysdk
#RUN pip3 install pypiwin32
RUN pip3 install unicodecsv
RUN pip3 install python-json-logger
```

After this I ran docker build .(this is second run, first run had installed odoo-client-lib and ebaysdk), below is the last portion of same:-

```
Step 37/41 : USER odoo
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c94d469bcaeb
Step 38/41 : RUN pip3 install odoo-client-lib
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 21c2e3aa65a2
Step 39/41 : RUN pip3 install ebaysdk
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f96a2763027a
Step 40/41 : RUN pip3 install unicodecsv
 ---> Running in b027d114aa1d
+ pip3 install unicodecsv
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting unicodecsv
  Downloading unicodecsv-0.14.1.tar.gz (10 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for unicodecsv, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: unicodecsv
  Running setup.py install for unicodecsv: started
  Running setup.py install for unicodecsv: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed unicodecsv-0.14.1
Removing intermediate container b027d114aa1d
 ---> 2034d07d53c0
Step 41/41 : RUN pip3 install python-json-logger
 ---> Running in b791123d5b2a
+ pip3 install python-json-logger
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting python-json-logger
  Downloading python_json_logger-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.4 kB)
Installing collected packages: python-json-logger
Successfully installed python-json-logger-2.0.2
Removing intermediate container b791123d5b2a
 ---> 25f582035703
Successfully built 25f582035703
```

Still when I use the built image, it shows these packages missing rest all 100+ python packages mentioned in requirements.txt are installed. Below is snippet from odoo pod using created image:-

```
odoo@odoo14uat-6686d57464-679cx:/etc/odoo$ pip3 show ebaysdk
WARNING: Package(s) not found: ebaysdk
odoo@odoo14uat-6686d57464-679cx:/etc/odoo$ pip3 show odoo-client-lib
WARNING: Package(s) not found: odoo-client-lib
odoo@odoo14uat-6686d57464-679cx:/etc/odoo$ pip3 show unicodecsv
WARNING: Package(s) not found: unicodecsv
odoo@odoo14uat-6686d57464-679cx:/etc/odoo$ pip3 show python-json-logger
WARNING: Package(s) not found: python-json-logger
odoo@odoo14uat-6686d57464-679cx:/etc/odoo$
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Why aren't these packages listed in the `requirements.txt` file?  `RUN pip install` individual packages isn't usually a best practice, it makes it harder to synchronize requirements between your non-Docker development environment and the deployed system.  I'd suggest updating `requirements.txt` to include _all_ of your application dependencies and deleting everything from the `chmod` call onwards; this will fix your problem if the `requirements.txt` packages are installed properly.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my question's beginning that earlier these 5 packages were part of requirements.txt. But still when the pod was created using that image the packages were missing so I specifically added them after line "USER odoo" to see if they show in pod.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed.

I commented the user odoo and continued with user root in Dockerfile, also added below line.

```
RUN pip3 install setuptools wheel
```

Added missing packages along with required versions(earlier I had not given specific version) in requirements.txt
Below is the snippet of revised requirements.txt

```
odoo-client-lib==1.2.2
ebaysdk==2.2.0
unicodecsv==0.14.1
python-json-logger==2.0.2
```

Below is the snippet of Dockerfile

```
#USER odoo
WORKDIR /etc/odoo
COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 install pip --upgrade
**RUN pip3 install setuptools wheel** --- New addition
RUN pip3 install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt
CMD chmod 755 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/*.py
USER odoo
```

Thanks.